# Не работает onblur react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

React js redux

У меня есть функция которая сохраняет значение в стор при onBlur c элемента, все вроде работает ок. Но если я нажимаю на кнопку которая переходит на другую страницу connected-react-router push, то onBlur не успевает отработать, как быть в этой ситуации
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете код показать?

Comment: @Randall onBlur в одном компоненте, onClick в другом

Comment: Код принято прикладывать текстом, а не картинками. Ну не удобно нам допустим КОПИРОВАТЬ с ваших картинок.

Comment: Варианты: 1. (Костыль) - добавить таймаут при переходе, 2. Сделать функцию обработчик клика, который будет выполнять действие блюра, а потом перенаправлять 3. пересмотреть логику компонента

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev это два разных компонента